# Solving a system of four polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I need to solve for 4 unknowns $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$ from 4 polynomial equations, three quadratic and one linear, given by the system

$$ (1-2c_{1})x_{1} - (1-2c_{2})x_{2} + c_{4}x_{2}x_{3} + (c_{2} - c_{1})x_{3}x_{4} + c_{3}x_{2}x_{4} - c_{4}x_{3}x_{1} - c_{3}x_{1}x_{4} = 0, \qquad (1)\\
(1-2c_{2})x_{2} - (1-2c_{3})x_{3} - c_{4}x_{1}x_{2} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{4} + c_{4}x_{1}x_{3} + (c_{3}-c_{2})x_{1}x_{4} + c_{1}x_{3}x_{4} = 0, \qquad (2)\\
(1-2c_{3})x_{3} - (1-2c_{4})x_{4} + (c_{4}-c_{3})x_{1}x_{2} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{3} - c_{2}x_{1}x_{3} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{4} + c_{2}x_{1}x_{4} = 0, \qquad (3)\\
\hspace{4.49in} x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 1, \qquad (4)$$

where the coefficients $c_{i} \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$, $\sum_{i=1}^{4}c_{i}=1$, and the unknowns $x_{i} \in (0,1)$ for $i=1,...,4$. Is there a systematic way to compute the $x_{i}$'s as explicit functions of $c_{i}$'s?

This system is a special case of a more general system, where some analysis shows that there is a unique solution under the stated assumptions on $c_i$'s and $x_i$'s. I am interested to explicitly find the solution in this 4 unknown case.

Comment: Not really. By numerical methods, do you mean Grobner basis? I am not particularly interested in specific numerical solution. If you mean doing that for making a guess, it seems nontrivial to do so even if we could solve it numerically. One particular solution I know: if $c_{1} = c_{2} = c_{3} = c_{4} = \frac{1}{4}$ then $x_{1}=x_{2}=x_{3}=x_{4} = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: I just tried running it using Mathematica as speicified and it ran for 1/2-hour with no convergence - so i wasn't sure if it was solvable generally. Anytime I see that - I try simpler examples to see if has any solutions, so Grobner basis would be one approach.

Comment: For ${\bf c}=(\frac14,\frac14,\frac1{16},\frac3{16})$ in [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690) `R=QQ[c1,c2,c3,c4,x1,x2,x3,x4]`
`I=ideal((1-2*c1)*x1 - (1-2*c2)*x2 + c4*x2*x3 + (c2 - c1)*x3*x4 + c3*x2*x4 - c4*x3*x1 - c3*x1*x4,(1-2*c2)*x2 - (1-2*c3)*x3 - c4*x1*x2 - c1*x2*x4 + c4*x1*x3 + (c3-c2)*x1*x4 + c1*x3*x4,(1-2*c3)*x3 - (1-2*c4)*x4 + (c4-c3)*x1*x2 - c1*x2*x3 - c2*x1*x3 + c1*x2*x4 + c2*x1*x4,x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 - 1,4*c1-1,4*c2-1,16*c3-1,16*c4-3)` `gens gb I` produces among other things a degree 6 polynomial in only `x4` and gives $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\approx (0.311,0.311,0.139,0.238)$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Your ${\bf c}=(\frac14,\frac14,\frac1{16},\frac3{16})$ is not normalized though. Nevertheless, this is encouraging. Can Grobner basis be computed symbolically?

Comment: Leaving the ${\bf c}$ unspecified will at best give you a similar process with these as parameters in similar degree polynomials in ${\bf x}$